# NSNetService Problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, bonjour

I am trying to establish a Bonjour connection between an iOS device and a Mac. Discovering each other is working great, but I am having problems with `setTXTRecordData:`. It always fails (BOOL returns NO)...

**_serviceInstances creation:**

```
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    [aNetService retain];

    [aNetService setDelegate:self];
    [aNetService startMonitoring];

    [aNetService performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resolve) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
[_serviceInstances addObject:aNetService];
}
```

Sending attempt:

```
NSNetService*service = [_serviceInstances objectAtIndex:[servicesTable selectedRow]];

[service setDelegate:self];

NSDictionary*txtRecordDataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2" forKey:@"Version"];

if (service)
{
    BOOL success = [service setTXTRecordData:[NSNetService dataFromTXTRecordDictionary:txtRecordDataDictionary]];   

    if (!success)
    {
        NSRunCriticalAlertPanel(@"Sync Error", @"Failed to contact Client. Please restart Carbon on your iPad and try again.", @"OK", nil, nil);
    }

    NSLog(@"Service: %@",service);
}
```

The NSLog message outputs `Service: <NSNetService 0x441b40> local. _test._tcp. David's iPad` which is correct.

iOS Code:

```
NSNetService*service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_test._tcp." name:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] port:28];
[service setDelegate:self];
[service setTXTRecordData:nil];
[service publish];

[service startMonitoring];


- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didUpdateTXTRecordData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Got Data! of %@",sender);

    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSDictionary*dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:nil];


    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:[sender name] message:[dict objectForKey:@"Version"]
                            delegate:self 
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [myAlert show];  
    [myAlert release];
}
```

For some reason, the alert is called when I launch the iPad app (blank contents except for the title) but doesnt respond to any signals from my Mac.

I am sure I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the publisher of the service can set the TXT record data. The discoverer of a published service can read the TXT record but cannot alter it. The TXT record provides a way for the publisher of the service to publish additional, publicly readable data that can be read from the DNS entry without having to contact the publisher directly.

***ETA:*** At least, `NSNetService`'s documentation makes it appear like you needn't resolve the service before you can grab the TXT record data. The `CFNetService` documentation notes that you must resolve the service before you can get the TXT record data. Both `CFNetService` and `NSNetService` seem to work only with a subset of the possible DNS-SD records that can be created and discovered using the C API described in `<dns_sd.h>`, which allows for attaching multiple TXT records to a single advertized service.

Comment: Old thread but this may helpful: As I understand it, it's not that the publisher of the `NSNetService` must set the `TXTRecordData` (or that it must be resolved first) but that this is the object that has access to the original `NSNetService` whereas the `NSNetServiceBrowser` finds a _copy_ of the original `NSNetService` (log the description of the original and the one found by the browser and you'll see they're different instances of `NSNetService`). So, setting the `TXTRecordData` on the service found by the browser is not setting it on the _original_ service and is therefore failing.